# Binding to ASP.NET GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have the following code:

```
var emp = new List<Employee>
{    
   new Employee{ID=1, EmpFname="matt", EmpLName="Cook"},  
   new Employee{ID=2, EmpFname="mary", EmpLname="John"}
};
```

How do I sort emp by EmpLName and bind it to a GridView? How do I specify asc or desc?

Answer (score 2):

```
        List<Employee> temp = new List<Employee> { 
            new Employee { ID = 1, EmpFname = "matt", EmpLName = "Cook" }, 
            new Employee { ID = 2, EmpFname = "mary", EmpLName = "John" } };

        temp.Sort(delegate(Employee e1, Employee e2)
        {
            // returns asc
            return e1.EmpLName.CompareTo(e2.EmpLName);
           // returns desc
           //  return e2.EmpLName.CompareTo(e1.EmpLName);

        });

        // no need to use var keyword, just bind the List 
        MyGridView.DataSource = temp;
        MyGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: +1  This is what i do too.  Your Employee needs a Sort() delegate method.  You can do this where you define your Employee class too.  Call Sort() on your List<Employee> then bind it.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way with LINQ:

```
var sortedEmpList = ( from e in emp
orderby e.EmpLName
select e).ToList()
);
```

you can also keep sorting by the other properties, by adding more of them after the **orderby**.

```
orderby e.EmpLName, e.EmpFName  //, ...
```

Then choose **descending** if you want that...

```
orderby e.EmpLName descending
```